# Will my Facebook comments get lost under these scenarios?

Tags: https, facebook, http, comments

I want to integrate Facebook comments to my blog.
According to my research, the page is treated as an object. So all the comments are tied to this object. This object itself is the page URL.
Now I have following questions.

1. If my page address is

   ```
   www.example.com/questions/1
   ```

   then I change my domain to

   ```
   www.example2.com/question/1
   ```

   Will it lose my comments?
2. Now my site has **http**. If I change it to **HTTPS** later will I lose my comments?
3. Currently, the page address is:

   ```
   www.example.com/questions/1
   ```

   if I change it to:

   ```
   www.example.com/question/1
   ```

   (ie. Removed `s` in `questions` word). Will I lose my comments?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you will lose all of your social activities if you change your domain or switch from HTTP to HTTPS. So, only point 3 above will not lose your activities count.

Answer (score 0):

Use facebook comment plugin which automatically update the comments in the fb to your blog